# How to launch web start on 10.10 OSX

Tags: macos, java

My wife is taking an online class and it says it needs to launch using Java Web Start.  I've changed the endings from `.ed` files to `.jnlp` files and make sure I click open other and select Java Web start.

Tech support wasn't helpful at all.

Comment: I don't know much about Java, but you need the JRE version rather than the 'consumer' version - see https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing Java for OS X 2014-001 it works.

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: I did this but still saying un able to open the application...